# Re-infer sequence type in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Suppose we have a sequence of `Any`

```scala
val seq = Seq(1,2,null)
seq: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2, null)
```

Now if one filters the non-null element obtains a new sequence

```scala
val cleanSeq = seq.filterNot(_ == null)
cleanSeq: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2)
```

Now I would like to obtain the same type as I would obtain if I create a new sequence like `cleanSeq`

```scala
val seq2 = Seq(1,2)
seq2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Can I obtain somehow `Seq[Int]` starting from `cleanSeq`?

**UPDATE**

The previous was only a dummy example and I can have other types than `Int`, also complex types example: `Array[Map[String, Float]]`.

The only assumption I can make is that I have a sequence which might contain nulls. But the other elements in the sequence have a common super type except `Any`. After removing the nulls, I want to find the common super type.

**UPDATE**

**The use case**

I want to create a spark dataframe from columns which have a name and values. The values are stored in a `Seq`. From the type of the `Seq` I want to derive the schema for the dataframe.

Definition of column

```scala
  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

  case class InternalColumn[A: TypeTag](colName: String, col: Seq[A]) {

    private def getType: DataType = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[A].dataType

    def genStructField: StructField = StructField(colName, getType)
  }
```

Creation of dataframe:

```scala
 def createDF[T](data: Seq[T], sch: StructType): DataFrame = {
    val dataRow: Seq[Row] = data.map {
      case row: Row => row
      case prod: Product => Row(prod.productIterator.toSeq: _*)
      case d => Row(d)
    }
    spark.createDataFrame(sc.makeRDD(dataRow), sch)
  }
```

Usage

```scala
  def createFromColumns(data: Seq[InternalColumn[_]]): DataFrame = {
    def loop(schema: StructType, cols: Seq[InternalColumn[_]]): StructType = cols.toList match {
      case Nil => schema
      case h :: t => loop(schema.add(h.genStructField), t)
    }

    val sch: StructType = loop(new StructType(), data)
    createDF(data.map(_.col).transpose.map(Row.fromSeq), sch)
  }

val df = createFromColumns(List(InternalColumn("c1", List(1,2,3)), InternalColumn("c2", List("a", "b", "c"))))

scala> df.show()
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
```

This works so far so good. But one might wants to create a dataframe which has a column containing nulls. If the column which has null is nullable, example it has `StringType` then it still works.

The problem appear when you have nulls in a column which is not nullable, ex:

```scala
scala> val df = createFromColumns(List(InternalColumn("c1", List(1,2,null)), InternalColumn("c2", List("a", "b", "c"))))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

This is the reason I want to infer the type of the sequence when I removed all the nulls.

Comment: If you can't know at compile time what the type should be then the compiler can't know either. The common super type of the elements which are in your Seq _at runtime_ is something that can only be known _at runtime_. So the compiler can't help there.

Comment: You probably have decent idea of the types at compile time, consider using `Either`

Comment: So if I get it right,  the short answer is no, it is not possible . Thanks!

Comment: It depends. Where do you get this `List(1,2,null)` from? If you have a black box somewhere that throws one or more `Seq[Any]` at you, then it's not possible to recover the type at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try not to lose the proper type in the first place (`Seq[Any]` is a bad code smell, as is using `null`), but to get back the real type you can do runtime typechecks:

```
 seq.collect{ case x: Int => x }
```

This will be `Seq[Int]` again, having thrown out everything that is not an `Int`.

If you didn't actually have other things in there, but just `Int` or `null`, consider using `Option[Int]` instead:

```
val seq: Seq[Option[Int]] = Seq(Some(1), Some(2), None)
// then you can do
seq.flatten // gives you Seq[Int]
```

> After removing the nulls, I want to find the common super type.

You do have to know (at the time you write the program) what that common super type is supposed to be. Then you can write code that checks against that type.

If you don't know that you want a `Seq[Int]` out of this, what will you declare the type of the result to be? Keep in mind that these generic types (the `Int` in `Seq[Int]`) are erased at runtime and only exist for the benefit of **static** type-checking at compile-time.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough.  This was only a dummy example, I don't know beforehand if I will face an Int. It could be String, Boolean, etc. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, and that kind of dynamically typed coding is very uncommon in Scala. We usually try to avoid this happening in the first place. Maybe you can expand on where you get this data from.